# how to get GA bigquery for firebase average enagement time, engaged session for user and average engaged time per session

Tags: google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

How to get the sql query that firebase uses in backend to fetch the data from google bigquery and display it in firebase dashboard is there any page where sample script is written. There are many similar question in stackoverflow where people got help but i couldn't figure out any specific question asked on this.Someone please help on this

[image]

Comment: Have a look at the guides on https://www.ga4bigquery.com/ . You will have to learn and query on your own to generate reports.

Comment: can i get the query if someone already written so that it will speed up my work

Comment: You will have to write query as per you business needs.

Comment: my requirement is same as how firebase display in his dashboard thats why asked

Comment: For your requirement, you can use GA4 BigQuery [export schema](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7029846?hl=en) and try writing [sample queries](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9037342?hl=en&ref_topic=7029512#zippy=%2Cin-this-article).

Comment: Hi @SahilSaxena, did the above comment help?